# Python Chat Server - Telnet error

Tags: python, linux

I have the following code which is supposed to implement a basic chat server on my localhost. The code has no errors (i dont get any erros thrown at me when i run the code). However when i run the program using `telnet` , i always get the error :

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I have made sure that the port i am trying to connect to is open. I am trying this out on `Ubuntu 12.04`. I have installed telnet. The code is as follows:

```
from asyncore import dispatcher
from asynchat import async_chat
import socket, asyncore

PORT = 5939
NAME = 'Chatbox'

class ChatSession(async_chat):
    def __init__(self,server,sock):
        async_chat.__init__(self, sock)
        self.server = server
        self.set_terminator("\r\n")
        self.data = []

    def collect_incoming_data(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)

    def found_terminator(self):
        line =''.join(self.data)
        self.data = []
        self.server.broadcast(line)

    def handle_close(self):
        async_chat.handle_close(self)
        self.server.disconnect(self)

class ChatServer(dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, port, name):
        dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind(('',port))
        self.listen(5)
        self.name = name
        self.sessions = []

    def disconnect(self, sessions):
        self.sessions.remove(session)

    def broadcast(self, line):
        for session in self.sessions:
            session.push('>>' + line + '\r\n')

    def handle_accept(self):
        conn, addr = self.accept()
        self.sessions.append(ChatSession(self, conn))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ChatServer(PORT, NAME)
    try: asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: print
```

I run the programs using the commands :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python chatbox.py
user@ubuntu:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5939
```

I am pretty sure its a minor issue in executing the program but I havent used linux before so I am unsure if my process is correct. Any help will b appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Ok so there where a few formatting errors in my code which i solved. Now when I run the code, the terminal goes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works perfectly except one thing. When client disconnect, following exception is raised:

```
....
  File "t.py", line 25, in handle_close
    self.server.disconnect(self)
  File "t.py", line 38, in disconnect
    self.sessions.remove(session)
NameError: global name 'session' is not defined
```

`ChatServer.disconnect` should be: (parameter name should be `session`, `sessions`)

```
def disconnect(self, session):
    self.sessions.remove(session)
```

Comment: I havent got the program to run yet so i have no clue about the error .

Comment: @Beginner, It works perfectly. Check `netstat -nlt` after you run the chat server. See http://asciinema.org/a/6906

Comment: AS i said in the update that the terminal window goes unresponsive and i have to kill the program. But the port get taken up because when i re run the program it says that the port is busy. Im confused.

Comment: @Beginner, Did you setup any firewall?

Comment: It works. I thought the program goes unresponsive but its actually running and i can access it via a new terminal. Thank so much for the help with that video. Upvoting for the help and effort